# Jquery Autocomplete not working in 1.5.1 but worked in 1.4.4

Tags: jquery

The following autocomplete code works with Jquery 1.4.4 but not with 1.5.1.  I am using jquery-ui-1.8.11.  I use the selected item to populate an array, the alert() call is just for testing purposes.  I aware of an autocomplete bug in 1.5 but thought 1.5.1 fixed it.  Any ideas on what I should do to get this working in 1.5.1?  My guess would be something with the json results, which are listed below.

```
$("#selected").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: autourl, type: "POST", dataType: "json",
            data: { query: request.term, maxResults: 10, donationid: donationid },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { Label: item.Label, value: item.Label, VolunteerID: item.VolunteerID, DisplayName: item.DisplayName, QtyFilled: item.QtyFilled }
                }))
            }
        })
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.DisplayName);
    }
});
```

The following is returned for 1.4 and 1.5.1.
[{"VolunteerID":1,"Label":"John Smith (jsmit@domain.com)","DisplayName":"John Smith","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Smith","AliasName":null,"QtyFilled":0}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you by chance using the validator plugin? There is a conflict between a previous version of the validator plugin and any 1.5.x jquery plugin. Downloading the updated validation plugin worked for me.

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

If this wasn't the issue, try removing any extensions and trim down the code so all you have left is the autocomplete code.

Comment: Works now since upgrading validation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with jQuery v1.5.2 - hot off the press:
http://blog.jquery.com/2011/03/31/jquery-152-released/

Comment: Tried v1.5.2 and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: Not yet, downgraded to 1.44 and UI 1.8.6 for now.  I noticed other things, like sortable, stopped working also.

Comment: I too am having problems with this :((